How to do multiple equation indentation with different offset
How can I reproduce this in latex?

So far I have tried:
\begin{align*}
    &min z(x) = c^Tx\\
    & \text{s.v.} &\\ \begin{split}
         & Ax \geq b \\
        & x \geq 0
    \end{split}
\end{align*}

but I can't get the secondo offset (after text) to force the following equation to align. Any suggestion on how to align at different offset like here?

Is this \begin{align*}     min z(x) &= c^Tx\\      \intertext{s.v.} \begin{split}           Ax &\geq b \\          x &\geq 0     \end{split} \end{align*} you expected?

@MadyYuvi Not quite. The text should be aligned to the first line, while the inequation should be aligned to an offset as big as the end of the text

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

You might want to make an environment out of this.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\subj}{\textit{s.v.}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 &\! \min z(x)=c^Tx \\
 &\subj \\
 &\qquad\begin{aligned}
   Ax &\ge b \\
   x  &\ge 0
  \end{aligned}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}



Here are two possible solutions. The first, which employs a single align* environment, aligns the = symbol in row 1 with the \geq symbols in rows 3 and 4. The second solution, which does not perform such a "global" alignment and instead performs pairwise alignments, employs two separate aligned environments inside a gather* environment.

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather*' and 'aligned' environments
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\min z(x) &= c^T\!x \\
\textit{s.v.}\qquad& \\
Ax &\geq b \\
x  &\geq 0
\end{align*}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned} % perform left-alignment of rows 1 and 2
&\min z(x) = c^T\!x \\
&\,\textit{s.v.}
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned} % align rows 3 and 4 on '\geq' symbols
Ax &\geq b \\
x  &\geq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}


From best Bernard's answer, Personalize the first \addConstraint using optidef package, another solution:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{optidef}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\bodySubjectToDefinition}{\kern 0.1em s.t.}{\kern 0.1em \textit{s.v.}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{mini*}|s|
{}{z(x)=c^Tx}{}{}
\addConstraint {Ax }{\geq b}{}
\addConstraint {x }{\geq 0}{}
\end{mini*}

\end{document} 


